# Is there a way to connect a JVM to a virtual disk or disk image file (.iso)

Tags: java, file-io, jvm, virtual-disk

I wanted to know if I could connect JVM to a virtual disk or disk image file (like .iso) by modifying the JVM source code.

Now let 'APP.jar' be an unknown java program that I downloaded from the internet. So this 'APP.jar' resides in my PC's file system.

My requirement is that, on running, 'APP.jar' should do all file reads or writes to this virtual disk only and should not be able to read or write to the file system on my pc.

If this is possible, Can someone explain how or can I get the link to some resources?

Comment: I'm not sure whether a Java application would be able to directly access an .iso file (however, it's basically just a file so why not?). Additionally you'd probably _not_ want to modify the JVM itself to provide for that if it isn't possible out-of-the-box. But since .iso images can be mounted why don't you just do that and allow the JVM access to that mounted filesystem only (via OS configuration)?

Comment: In principle, of course. But if you have to ask such a question, I doubt that *you* are capable of doing the necessary modifications to the source code…